# Scripts and white spaces

Tags: linux, macos, bash, replace

I have a simple bash find and replace script 'script.sh' :

```
#!/bin/bash 
find . -type f -name '.' -exec sed -i '' "s/$1/$2/" {} +
```

When I run my command ./script.sh foo bar, it works. Suppose now my two inputs strings $1 and $2 are sentences (with white spaces), how can I make the script to recognize each of them as whole strings ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add each sentence in quotes `"`

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $1
echo $2
```

output

```
$ ./tmp.sh "first sentence" "second sentence"
first sentence
second sentence
```

Edit:

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
find . -type f -exec sed -i "s/$1/$2/" {} +
```

Ouput:

```
$ cat test1.txt 
ola sdfd
$ ./tmp.sh "ola sdfd" "hello world"
$ cat test1.txt 
hello world
$ ./tmp.sh "hello world" "ols asdf"
$ cat test1.txt 
ols asdf
```

Comment: tryied here's now my output sed: 1: "./.DS_Store": invalid command code .

Comment: @info : I need to process a recursive find and replace

Comment: @user1611830  could you post the command you are running? including the arguments...

Comment: ./script.sh "My first sentence" "My second sentence". I don't know why but the recursive find is failing

Comment: @user1611830 Note that I removed the `-name '.'` Do you need it?

Comment: Yep I'have just removed it also on my side and it works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to screen spaces with \?
e.g.: this\ is\ sample\ string\ with\ spaces

Comment: it seems indeed to correct the input but now the find and replace script is not working anymore...

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call your script as :

```
./myscript  "sentence 1 with spaces" "sentence 2"
```

But you may have to "escape" special characters (or use something else than sed)

You may want to add `g` to the sed `s/.../.../` construct so that it replaces several occurence on the same line.

And you can't have a string with a `/` in it, as you use `/` as the sed's separator. (You can change that separator to anything, for example to the unlikely `%` :  `s%$1%$2%g`)

Comment: You mean to change "s/$1/$2/" into s%$1%$2%g ? I did but the script is nor finding nor replacing